# WPF ComboBox Refresh After Collection Update

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am using `ComboBox` in `wpf` as below and want to update `ComboBox` behind the seen if i update collection :-

```
     <xmlns:dataProvider="clr-namespace:DataProvider"
     <UserControl.Resources>
        <dataProvider:BackOfficeDataProvider x:Key="DataProvider"/>
     </UserControl.Resources>
    <ComboBox x:Name="groupGroupNameCombo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="368,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226" Height="31" SelectionChanged="groupGroupNameCombo_SelectionChanged"    DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" SelectedItem="{Binding ParentID, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupParentList, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Source={StaticResource DataProvider}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

                        </ComboBox>

    Class BackOfficeDataProvider {
    public static ObservableCollection<Categories> groupParentList = null;
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Categories> GroupParentList
            {
                get { return groupParentList ; }
                set
                {
                    groupParentList = value;
                    // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
                    OnPropertyChanged("GroupParentList");
                }
            }

    public void loadComboListData();
    {
    GroupParentList = (ObservableCollection<Categories>) //fetching data from database using NHibernate directly getting list ;
    }
}
```

my front end class which has refresh button :-

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          new BackOfficeDataProvider().loadComboListData();
        }
```

when application load that time i can see the item in `combobox` but when i click on Refresh button that time it load updated data from database but not updating `combobox` untill i use below code

```
groupGroupNameCombo.ItemsSource = null;
groupGroupNameCombo.ItemSource = GroupParentList ;
```

Its a manually thing i have to do always to refresh `combobox`, how can i make it automatic like if i update collection then it should update `combobox` at the same time and i don't need to use above workaround.

Comment: Fetch data from Database. Can you post the logic

Comment: The GroupParentList Property is not static so you can not access it in the static loadComboListData method. Are you sure you are not setting the groupParentList (notice lower case g) which is the static field not the property instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have something to do with breaking the coupling between the combobox and the ObservableCollection when doing this:

```
GroupParentList = //fetching data from database;
```

Try this instead:

```
var dbCategories = // Get data from DB
GroupParentList.Clear(); 
foreach (var item in dbData)
    GroupParentList.Add(item);
```

The point is to update the items in the collection, not the collection itself.

Also, try defining your collection like this, it should'nt have to be instantiated more than once (i.e no setter):

```
public static ObservableCollection<Categories> groupParentList = null;
public virtual ObservableCollection<Categories> GroupParentList
{
    get 
    {
        if (groupParentList == null)
            groupParentList = new ObservableCollection<Categories>();
        return groupParentList; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For answer i have instantiated collection only once. But if i use your `foreach` loop approach then it will be like manually thing again. because in my application number of operation is updating  GroupParentList using background worker thread and running `foreach` wont be efficient approach as per my thought.

Answer (score 0):

Hogler is right, your approach of assigning a new ObservableCollection object to the binding property will break how binding works. For ObservableCollection to work, you will need to modify the items in the collection itself, ObservableCollection is responsible of publishing list changes to the binding target. When you assign a new collection to the binding target, the list will not get refresh unless you published PropertyChanged event again to register this new binding source.

In your later comment you did state that you only instantiate ObservableCollection once only, which is not obvious from your posted code. It appears to me that the reason why it doesn't work is because you assign a new collection to the "GroupParentList" each time you run "loadComboListData".

Comment: Right, I agree what you said, But don't you think i will impact performance. Performance was my only concern.

Comment: How many items in the list for combobox? Generally it shouldn't be a huge list for combobox, and enumerating a small list has very minimal impact on performance. Maybe you can elaborate further on your thoughts on how it might be a significant impact?

Answer (score -2):

Try this ..
once You are done getting data from your database in `groupParentList` , Add below Line, it will work as below :-

```
GroupParentList = new ObservableCollection<Categories>(groupParentList )
```

Comment: this is same as what i am doing in `loadComboListData()` method;

Comment: First get data into your private member (groupParentList ) then assign it to public property like i have mentioned below :                                                   GroupParentList = new ObservableCollection<Categories>(groupParentList ).   .